# Angular: plugin or a tool for memory view

Tags: angular, performance, debugging, memory

I'm looking for a plugin or a tool to explore objects in memory during a debug session (for bugfix, improvement ...), something like [memory view](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/jvm-debugger-memory-view-for-intellij-idea/) in intellij, as it will make it easy for me to find leaks ( instance of services not destroyed, unsubscribed subsciption ... ).

Comment: Asking for recommendations for off-site resources, or tools is off topic. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Try Developer tools in chrome, there is performance tab.

[image]

Comment: But this will help you see the CPU chart, and not the objects themselves.

Comment: Please see updated answer, I have added a screenshot showing the profiler in action. From there you can check the depth of the call stack, time consumed by each function and etc. If you want to look at the memory heap, you can use the memory tab in the same tool.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it helps.